# Unable to fetch records when using between in date range in sql

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

When I use the following query in SQL, no records have been returned.

```
select distinct e.No from attendance a
inner join Employee e on a.EmployeeId =e.No
where e.No not in (select EmployeeId from attendance where AttendanceDate between '2017-05-26 00:00:00' and '2017-06-06 00:00:00')
```

But when I single date instead of date range, it works fine. e.g.

```
select distinct e.No from attendance a
inner join Employee e on a.EmployeeId =e.No
where e.No not in (select EmployeeId from attendance where AttendanceDate = '2017-06-06 00:00:00' )
```

Can someone please help me out to solve this issue as I have to use a date range instead of a particular date.

Comment: Are you sure that there is data in that date range which should be returned?

Comment: Yes because it return records on individual dates

Comment: Have you tried using `between '2017-05-26' and '2017-06-06'` ?

Comment: Yes I did, but still no records found.

Comment: Can you post sample data?  May be it is normal your query doesn't return records as you are using NOT IN (in the second case data range is less selective)

Comment: Sorry I can not post sample data as it is confidential. However I can tell you that when I use single date instead of date range it does return the records... I am actually trying to find all those employee records which do not have entries in the attendance table... I have checked single date from 26 May til date and it does return records correctly

Comment: What is the type of the `AttendanceDate` column?

Comment: @ASK:  just for the future: you should prepare TEST sample data, so you can post it freely.

Comment: smalldatetime 

@etsa sure I will. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about the logic of your query:

```
select distinct e.No
from attendance a
inner join Employee e
    on a.EmployeeId = e.No
where e.No not in
(
    select EmployeeId from attendance
    where AttendanceDate between '2017-05-26 00:00:00' and '2017-06-06 00:00:00'
)
```

If the subquery were to return *every* employee number in the `Employee` table, then you would get back *no* records from the query.  This is how `WHERE NOT IN (...)` behaves.  My guess is that the reason the single date query appears to be "working" is that no employee records match to that date, and hence your result set is not empty.

If you expect the opposite behavior, then perhaps you should change `WHERE e.No NOT IN` to `WHERE e.No IN`.

Comment: I have to find all those employees that were present during these days and yet there attendance is not marked (no record present in the attendance table) 
So my logic works perfectly fine on single date. I have cross checked it with both tables. but when I give a date range, it just don't return any record

Comment: `it just don't return any record` ... then as I said, maybe you intend to do `WHERE IN`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Actually no.. the sub query returns all those employee ids which have records in the attendance table, So I just unselect those ids using not in and fetch the remaining ids which have no records in the attendance table in the mentioned date

Answer (score 0):

if you run the select in your where statement do you get any results?

try it without the time on it:

```
between '2017-05-26' and '2017-06-06'
```

what date format are you using?

Comment: Yes it returns records. and Its in 2017-05-26 00:00:00 format